# Force Logout for Specific Users

Tags: users, database

Our Drupal 7.5 website is having an issue where users click logout but they are sent to the front page still logged in. I believe it's related to a bakery module, however, the question I am asking here is this: how do I force logout for specific users (not all users) via command line?

I tried:

```
drush uinf <username>
```

(To get user ID)

```
drush sql-query "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE uid = <uid>;"
```

The end result was a sql deadlock that crashed the site momentarily, and when it came back up, the user was still logged in. Should the sql command have worked? If so, then I may need to troubleshoot other issues.

Update: I disabled the bakery module and the problem went away, so the command was correct, but something about the module was wrong. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled the Bakery module and am now able to clear the flood tables using the command without getting the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to install the [masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade), masquerade  as that user and in the url: `user/logout`. It also works and like this: `user/login`

Other options:

[Drush login, Drush logout](https://gist.github.com/c4rl/4035400)

and this related post: [How to logout all active users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21681/how-to-logout-all-active-users) suggestes to empty the sessions table, well while you only want for one selected user, do a join if needed and specify the `$uid`